# intento mostrar los datos de mi bd en una tabla y me da fatal error

Tags: php, sql

estoy intentando mostrar en una tabla todos los datos que contiene mi base de datos y me aparece un fatal error, es este: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::mysqli_num_rows().

como se observa en el codigo intento mostrar cada uno de los datos en cada una de las lineas de la tabla y mediante el while hago el ciclo para que muestre todas las rows que existan en mi base de datos.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM rock";
        $resultado=$conexion->query($sql);
        $num=$conexion->mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

            while ($i < $num) {

                $cedula=$row["cedula"];
                $nombre=$row["nombre"];
                $apellido=$row["apellido"];
                $direccion=$row["direccion"];
                $telefono=$row["telefono"];

        ?>

        <table>
        <caption>Rock Sinfonico</caption>

        <div class="busqueda">
        <form action="" method="">          
            <input  type="search" size="10" placeholder="Buscar...">                
            <button>Buscar</button>
        </form>
        </div>

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Cedula</th>
                <th>Direccion</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $nombre; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $apellido; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $cedula; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $direccion; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $telefono; ?></td>
                <td> <a href="">Editar</a></td>
                <td> <a href="">Eliminar</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<?php
    
    $i++;
    }   
        $conexion->close();

?>
```

Comment: Aquí `$num=$conexion->mysqli_num_rows($resultado)` estás usando la conexión para llamar a `mysqli_num_rows`. Si lees la documentación verás que esa función es parte de un conjunto de resultados, no de la conexión. Además, estás mezclando estilos (procedural y orientado a objetos), lo cual no es recomendable, precisamente el error en esa línea se debe a la confusión entre ambos estilos. Te recomiendo que uses solo el estilo orientado a objetos. La línea debe quedar así: `$num=$resultado->num_rows;` de ese modo debería funcionar a no ser que haya errores adicionales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay al menos dos errores en tu código:

Aquí `$num=$conexion->mysqli_num_rows($resultado)` estás usando la conexión para llamar a `mysqli_num_rows`. Si lees la documentación verás que esa función es parte de un conjunto de resultados, no de la conexión. Además, estás mezclando estilos (procedural y orientado a objetos), lo cual no es recomendable, precisamente el error en esa línea se debe a la confusión entre ambos estilos. Te recomiendo que uses solo el estilo orientado a objetos. La línea debe quedar así: `$num=$resultado->num_rows;`

Por otra parte, `mysqli` tiene sus propios métodos para obtener los resultados, son los métodos `fetch_`, que puedes revisar también en la documentación. Como tienes el `while` actualmente no podrás leer los resultados.

Generalmente lo que se haces es verificar con `num_rows` si hay filas y luego usar uno de los métodos `fetch_` para mostrar los resultados.

Debes refinar un poco la lógica en tu programa. La tabla debe llenarse únicamente cuando se haya comprobado que hay datos. Además, debes construir los `tr` dentro del `while` que leería los datos.

Te dejo la corrección del código y de la logica en las partes esenciales, solo es cuestión de completar en tu entorno:

```
#Verificamos si hay filas directamente
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
    #Deberias empezar aquí a construir la tabla, no antes
    #Pon AQUI todo lo previo a tu tabla, los divs,
    #el form, etc. La cuestión es empezar a crear esa parte
    #una vez se haya verificado que la consulta trae datos 
    #Damos por supuesto que ya tienes las etiquetas
    #de apertura de tabla, los encabezados, el tbody etc ...
    #... ahora escribimos los tr y td dentro del while
    #usando un método fetch adecuado
    #Concatenaremos todas las filas en una variable
    #para dar claridad al código y evitar tantas mezclas
    #de bloques PHP/HTML
    $mRows="";
    while ($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $mRows.="<tr>
                      <td>$row[cedula]</td>
                      <td>$row[nombre]</td>
                      <td>$row[apellido]</td>
                      <td>$row[direccion]</td>
                      <td>$row[telefono]</td>  
                </tr>";
    }
    #Ahora imprimimos todas las filas
    #Como ya dije, acopla adecuadamente
    #los demás elementos de tu tabla 
    echo $mRows;
} else {
    #Si no hay filas imprimes un mensaje o lo que quieras
    echo "No se encontraron filas";
}
$conexion->close();
```

Esa es la lógica a seguir para un código coherente, organizado y más limpio. Si hay dudas dímelo comentando está respuesta. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias padre, la mejor respuesta y mejor trato que me han dado hasta ahora en esta plataforma, todo muy claro. gracias por los consejos

Comment: @DiegoGoncalves me alegro de que te haya servido la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: padre, estoy intentando crear un boton de editar y de eliminar en los campos de las tablas que se muestran y solo consigo tener errores, alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: @DiegoGoncalves Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas. Si han surgido un nuevo problema (aunque sea sobre el mismo código o programa) debes abrir una nueva pregunta con ese nuevo problema, así tendrá mayor visibilidad y podrás recibir más ayuda de diferentes miembros del sitio.

Comment: gracias por el dato.